# Should analytics cookies be HttpOnly?

Tags: penetration-test, cookies

Should ga gid gat and Fbp cookies be flagged as Secure and HttpOnly?
Is there a way an attacker can use them if accessed?

Comment: The general question should be if those cookies give access to any privileges. What is the *impact* of rogue access?

Comment: I think the question should be "What can an unauthorized third party do with analytics cookies?" and is probably a better fit for [webmasters.se], since I believe they know more about analytics cookies than we may.

Answer (score 3):

A better question is: is there a reason *not* to make them HttpOnly?

By default, you should mark all cookies as HttpOnly. If you discover that the cookies need to be read by on-page JavaScript, then you should investigate the reason for this requirement and weigh up the risks and benefits. If the risk is minimal or manageable, and the benefits are commensurate, then you should remove the HttpOnly flag.

This goes for almost every security control. Your baseline approach should be as secure as reasonably possible by default. When you come across business processes and requirements that are impeded by those security controls, you should assess the situation (preferably with a threat modelling approach) and decide on an outcome. That might mean finding an alternative approach that fulfils the business requirement without changing the security controls. It might mean just accepting the risk. It might mean that you disable the security control that's causing problems, but applying mitigating controls elsewhere to lower the risk.

As for tracking IDs in particular, they're generally benign enough that an attacker can't really use them for anything but privacy violation. Your average attackers generally aren't really interested in them.

As for mitigations, you can't really mitigate the privacy violation part, because that's kinda the whole point of tracking cookies, but you can make attempts to protect against unintentional disclosure via plaintext HTTP connections (Secure flag) and XSS attacks (HttpOnly flag). Whether or not the potential privacy violation caused by a leaked tracking cookie is a risk to your users depends on the context - an online shop selling fancy tea bags has a very different risk profile to a website for victims of domestic abuse. That risk calculation and the resulting security decision is something that you have to make for yourself.